# using different themes for different languages with i18n in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, internationalization, drupal-modules

I am developing a website which has both English and Arabic versions. I have installed Arabic language and the i18n module, which is working fine and I am able to add Arabic translation for the English contents.The URL prefix 'site.com/ar' is also working fine.

Since Arabic is a right-to-left language I want to show different theme for the Arabic content,which contains images with Arabic text etc.(a flipped or mirror version of the English theme with Arabic text).

Is there any good solution for this scenario where site.com/ar should show the Arabic theme and site.com/en should show the English theme?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the [Sections module](http://drupal.org/project/sections) to switch the themes, based on the path.

I'm not sure if this would help with right-to-left languages, but you may also consider [adding body classes based on the language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004041/include-templates-based-on-current-language-with-drupal/5005198#5005198) and using those to modify the theme.

You may also find [Notes on Setting up a Drupal Site for Internationalization](http://openconcept.ca/blog/kevin/notes_setting_drupal_site_internationalization) and/or [Internationalization & RTL Drupal Theming](http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/support/theme-developers/compatibility-standards/internationalization-rtl-right-left-drupal-theming) helpful.